# Throwing another exception inside @ExceptionHandler in spring boot is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I'm having a CustomException which I handle with the `@ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)`

In one case I'll be getting a `InvalidFormatException` so from there I need to rethrow to my CustomException. I tried throwing the exception but it's not working as expected

```
    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidFormatException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public Error invalidFormat(InvalidFormatException e) throws CustomException {
      if (logicToValidate()) {
        throw new CustomException();
      } else {
        return new Error(BAD_REQUEST.name(), e.getMessage(), ErrorLevel.ERROR);
      }
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
    public Error customException(CustomException e) {
      ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I found this thread https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18299. So it's not possible for now to rethrow the exception in spring boot. Instead we can try alternative strategy, if we have any.